# random image and paired text pick javascript

Tags: javascript, image, random

I have images and texts to display to people as a result when they upload their pic in input box.

I want set-images and texts to be shown to them as a pair but it should be picked randomly in the pool.

So, simply saying,

people upload their pics to input box.

one of matched image and text in the pool randomly to be appeared to them as a result.

please give me some advice. I'm stuck in here for a week!!

```js
    function randomImg(){
            var quote = [
                {
                    text: "1",
                    img: "Img/1.jpg"},
                
                {
                    text: "2",
                    img: "Img/2.jpg"},
                
                {
                    text: "3",
                    img: "Img/3.jpg"},
                
                {
                    text: "4",
                    img: "Img/4.JPG"},
            ];
        var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
            document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
                '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
                '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
        }
```

```html
    <p>
    <input class="Randombutton" style="float: left;" type="button" 
    value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg()">
    </p>
```

Comment: Run the code in the snippet and observe the error message which appears on screen.
(I'm trying to trick you into solving the problem yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a few typos in your solution:

1. You're missing an element with the ID "quote". In my solution below I put a `div` as a placeholder, but you can use whatever you want.
2. In your `randomImg` function, your array is called `quote`, but you later look up the text and image URL from `quotes` (with an s).

Fixing both of these will update the image and text to a pseudo-random element in your array.

These types of errors will show up in the developer tools of the browser, so I'd recommend checking those out as well!

```html
<div>
  <input class="Randombutton" style="float: left;" type="button" value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg()">
</div>
<br />
<div id="quote"></div>

<script>
  function randomImg() {
    var quotes = [{
        text: "1",
        img: "Img/1.jpg"
      },

      {
        text: "2",
        img: "Img/2.jpg"
      },

      {
        text: "3",
        img: "Img/3.jpg"
      },

      {
        text: "4",
        img: "Img/4.JPG"
      },
    ];
    var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
      '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
      '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. but if you wouldn't mind, would you help me more please? i need your help, Patrick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808762/random-image-print-javascript         please